# Asp.net website running error

Tags: asp.net

On running my asp.net website which is deployed in local IIS , I got a message
 **User-agent: * Disallow: /**. Why did I get this message? How can I overcome this problem and run my website successfully?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That's your `robots.txt` file. If you're getting that for any request then your webserver is seriously misconfigured.

Comment: Can you show me more detail ? A screenshot or something !

Answer (score 1):

This is the entry in your `robots.txt` file.

Translated, it means this:

The `User-agent: *` means this section applies to all robots. The `Disallow: /` tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on the site.

Note: Check in your top-level directory for a `robots.txt` file and either remove it or change the configuration to allow access.